# Unable to Install Drivers or GTX Experience

Tags: drivers, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

Computer Type: Desktop - ASUS M52BC_M32BC

GPU: SKU: 574228 2 GB GDDR5 Overclocked Not in SLI

CPU: AMD FX-4300 Quad Core, not overclocked

Motherboard: Provide the model number.

RAM: Model# BLS4G3D18ADS3 16 Gigs Not Overclocked

PSU: CP-9020077 650w

Operating System & Version: Win 10x64

GPU Drivers: 358.91

Chipset Drivers: AMD 970

Background Applications: Any/None (Happens with both)

Description of Problem: Both Driver updates and GTX Experience are refusing to install though they give no usable error.

Troubleshooting: I uninstalled all nvidia software except for the current driver 358.91 and tried to reinstall Experience, thinking maybe it'd help.

It did not, now experience won't reinstall either.

Update: I attempted to manually install the drivers through device manager and received "system could not allocate the required space in a registry log". Quick google search said this was easily solved by clearing some space from the system partition of your drive.

Two problems.

1. I still had 50 some gb of space on my system drive.
2. After deleting multiple programs issue is still ongoing.

Comment: extract the driver Exe and update the driver via device manager: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/97061-driver-install-device-manager.html

Comment: @magicandre1981 See above update.

Comment: please share the file "C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log"

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RXFxD7rp2FfAbQNMoFdVTgt-Mylbyj2raSjoIRX9s5c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've asked someone at Microsoft for help. I'll post here again if I get a reply with advices.

Comment: My contact asked nVIDIA, but haven't heared anything from them. Also try to capture a process monitor trace of the install failure: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx (save it as PML, zip the file, upload the zip to OneDrive and post a share link here)

Comment: ok, the Microsoft employee talked a bit about it in his show: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Error-Installing-GPU-Driver-Manually-Installing-1511-Reactivating-After-a-Reinstall-and-more#time=4m12s Also provide details of your system by runnning msinfo32 and save the report into a file.

Comment: any updates? Have you tried to capture a procmon trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are some weird driver issues that can sometimes occur when you update the non-clean format way from Win * to Win 10. Was fixed with a clean install.

Comment: but hav you captured any of the requested data?